# jQueryUI setting options in a variable - syntax for effects

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-ui, dialog

```
$(function(){
        var dialogOpts = {
        autoOpen:       false,
        height:         400,
        width:          600,
        position:       ["center", "center"],
        modal:          false,
        closeOnEscape:  true,
        stack:          true,
        draggable:      true,
        show:           "clip",
        hide:           "bounce"
    };
```

I'm setting the above options for a jQuery UI Dialog but want to dictate some options for each of the effects, such as speed and number of bounces etc, but I can't find an example of the syntax anywhere.

I've tried

```
show: ["clip", 100],
```

and the like but they're not hitting the mark.  Can you suggest anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the current version of jQuery UI, however, you're not the first person wanting this.  If you look at [Ticket #2358](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/2358) you can get the patch needed to accomplish this.  Once you apply [dialog2.patch](http://dev.jqueryui.com/attachment/ticket/2358/dialog2.patch) to your `ui.dialog.js` you can use this syntax:

```
show: { effect:"clip", options:{}, speed:100 }
```

**This will not work without the patch**, jQuery UI doesnt' natively support it.  This is the community adding functionality, which hopefully will land in a future jQuery UI release.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8rc3/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js) source code uses the following command to show the dialog:

```
uiDialog.show(options.show);
```

So you are not going to be able to pass additional options to `show` because the code is not expecting them. In order to do so, you will probably have to create your own custom version of the dialog code. Which is not *that* hard to do since the source code is freely available, but it is work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide option, it's probably in an object and not an array try:

```
show : { "clip": 100},
```